# Passively listening on a socket for a chat application

Tags: java, swing, sockets, concurrency, event-dispatching

I am currently developing a chat application which is quite basic overall, however I am encountering problems when receiving strings from both the client and the server side. I am using a thread to passively listen on the socket for incoming messages, which is where I suspect the problem to be. Am I doing this the right way?

Source: 
Code for sending strings:

```
send.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            messageBuffer = message.getText();
            out.println(messageBuffer);
            chat.append(username + ": " + messageBuffer + "\n");
            message.setText("");
        }
    });
```

I then have this which passively listens (problem is probably here):

```
public void run(){
    while(true){
        try {
               messageBufferIn = in.readLine();
               System.out.println(in.readLine());
               chat.append(recipient + ": " + messageBufferIn + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Im also calling the thread using this:

```
public static void startChatting(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide, Im still new to threads overall so my mistake might be quite mediocre.

Edit: The problem is when I try sending a message to the receiver, nothing comes through, I can confirm that they are connected. In fact the System.out.println(in.readLine()); doesnt come through at all, not even a "null" output.

Comment: And the problem is what exactly...?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) will help..

Comment: @user1329572 I have been told using while loops when listening on a socket for data is a bad CPU clog. Is this correct, or is this the only way?

Comment: Most of the reader's will actually block (or stop) thread execution until some input is received.  So in the background, the reader is doing what you're redoing by telling the thread to sleep (meaning you really don't need to do it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you have got issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), Swing GUI don't know that you running / open the `Socket` on `Background Task`,
2. all updates to the `Swing GUI` must be done on [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), otherwise nothing happened or you got a few exceptions
3. have to wrap all updates from `Background Task` (in your case `Runnable#Thread`) to the `invokeLater`  for Swing GUI
4. `while(true){` is endless loop put there `Boolean variable` instead of `true`, then you can to stop, start or restart whatever in your case `Socket`
5. in the case that `send.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){` runs only once time (if user invoked by `JButtons` click) then to use [SwingWoker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) for opening Socket, `SwingWorker` quite good guarantee that all output should be done on EDT
6. difference betweens `Runnable#Thread` and `SwingWorker` is that `SwingWorker` is designated to run only once times

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your main problem is that you're not flushing the `OutputStream`.  You'll want to add `out.flush()` after you've finished writing to it and want to send the message.  For example, your `ActionListener` would look like this:

```
send.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        messageBuffer = message.getText();
        out.println(messageBuffer);
        out.flush();
        chat.append(username + ": " + messageBuffer + "\n");
        message.setText("");
    }
});
```

If you don't do this, your `OutputStream` will sit there until it's buffer's full (which will be a lot of messages).